# How to make it exit in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

```
import pygame
import os
pygame.font.init()
pygame.mixer.init()

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 900, 500
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("TIMER")
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)
MENU_bg = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("menu.png")), (WIDTH, HEIGHT))
SPACE = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("SPACE.png")), (WIDTH, HEIGHT))
START_button = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("START.png")), (300, 150))
STOP_button = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("STOP.png")), (300, 150))
RESET_button = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("RESET.png")), (300, 150))
re = 0
FPS = 100
FONT = pygame.font.SysFont("Comic sans", 100)
FONT2 = pygame.font.SysFont("Comic sans", 30)
quiting = 0


def test_exit():
    if quiting == 1:
        exit()
    else:
        pass

def draw_menu():
    WIN.blit(MENU_bg, (0, 0))
    pygame.display.update()

def main_menu():
    running = True
    quiting = 0
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    FPS = 60
    draw_menu()
    while running:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        draw_menu()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                quiting = 1
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                print(mouse_pos)
                if mouse_pos[0] >= 0 and mouse_pos[0] <= 450 and mouse_pos[1] >= 200 and mouse_pos[1] <= 500:
                    #I will connect to a new function here
                    running = False




if __name__ == "__main__":
    main_menu()
```

Why it didn't exit normally? I tried many times but it don't work. I get no error messages when running the code, but I could not exit. I have read several tutorials and don´t see what I´ve done wrong. How can I change my code to make it exit when **pygame.QUIT**?

Answer (score 0):

You never called the `test_exit` function.

```
import pygame
import sys

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 900, 500
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))

def test_exit(quiting):
    if quiting:
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            test_exit(True)
```

Note that `exit` doesn't close the pygame window. You will have to use `pygame.quit()` for that. Call  `sys.exit()` after that if you want to terminate your program.

Answer (score 0):

you can just simply change running to `False` the code will stop immediately

```
if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
    running = False
```